# Example of a sheaf without locally free resolution

Tags: complex-geometry, coherent-sheaves

By the Syzygy theorem it follows that any coherent $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$-module $\mathcal{F}$ has a locally free resolution
$$\dots \to F_1 \to F_0 \to \mathcal{F} \to 0,$$
where the $F_i$ are locally free $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$-modules.

If I understand correctly, it is not in general possible to construct locally free resolutions, and my question is simply:

**Question:**
Are there any simple examples of a complex manifold $X$ and a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ which does not have a locally free resolution?

Hints, comments, and references are appreciated.

Comment: See appendix in https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~claire.voisin/Articlesweb/hodgeimrn.pdf